# Extract elements from array and then update their fields using Logic Apps

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-cosmosdb, crm, azure-logic-apps

I wish to grab the elements in the Feedbacks array and then update two fields within that ids array:

```
"Feedbacks": 

  [

     {

     "ids": "1234"

     }

    {

    "ids": "4567"

    }
]
```

update this

```
"id":"1234"
"Features":

 [

{
  "id": "change this"
  "status": "change this"
}

 ]


"id": "4567"
"Features":  

   [
        
  {

    "id": "change this"
    "status": "change this"

  }
]
```

I believe I may have to do this, does this look correct please, is this the correct approach?

Create two local variables that will update status and id.

I am seeing that I cannot dynamically put in the 'FeatureID' on variable 2 though because it is globally above the CDS step.

[image]
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you

```
   JSON ORIGINAL DATA THAT HOLDS FEEDBACK ARRAY IN BOLD
 {
  "Blocking": "test",
  "CRMLink": null,
  "Contact": "test",
  "CreatedBy": null,
  "DomainOwnerPriority": null,
  "FeatureCategory": "test",
  "FeatureCreatedOnDate": null,
  "FeatureId": "test",
  "FeaturePM": "test",
  "FeatureTitle": "test",
  "FeedbackDescription": "test",
  "FeedbackName": "test",
  "FeedbackSource": "test",
  "FeedbackSourceLink": "test",
  "FeedbackSubmittedBy": "test",
  "FeedbackType": "test",
  *"Feedbacks": [
                       {
                        "id":"1234"
                       }
                 ],*
  "GPM": null,

 }
```

JSON ORIGINAL DATA THAT HOLDS FEATURES ARRAY

```
 {
  "id": "123",
  "feedback": {
  "Blocking": "",
  "CContact": "",
  "Competition_Details": "",
  "Count_Of_Comments": "0",
  "Count_Of_Votes": 0,
  "Domain_Area": "",
  **"Features": [**
      {
        **"id": "something",
        "state": "something"**
      }
    ],
   "Feedback_CreatedOn_Date": "test",
   "Feedback_Description": "text",
   "Feedback_EnteredIn_Amalgam_Date": "test",
   "Feedback_Name": "test",
   "Feedback_Source": "test",
   "Feedback_Source_ID": "test",
   "Feedback_Source_Link": "test",
   "Feedback_Submitted_By": "test",

}
```

Hi, I am trying to access the Feedback array which hold these ids. Once I loop over each id, (ex. 1234) I need to change the Features array within the 'ids' and update the id and status.
I think the correct approach is to create a variable, do a for each loop and do an update. I am just not sure and would appreciate any advice

Comment: Hi Lynnette, could you please share a json sample of your original data ? and share a json sample of what you want ?

Comment: According to your previous post, it seems there is another level outside `Feedbacks`, so please share the whole oringinal data. I'm a little confused about your requirement after reading your last three posts.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen thank you if you can provide some insight this will be wonderful. I am stuck on this. I updated the post. I need to essentially loop over the 'Feedbacks' array , which hold these id fields. Within these ids, they hold a features array that I must update their id and state fields.

Comment: Where does the data of `Features`(the `id` and `state`) come from ?

Comment: They are all within a container within CosmosDB

Comment: I have a Features and Feedback container in CosmosDB where this data is stored

Comment: I just do not know how to have the Logic App point to the 'id' and 'state' fields to update because they are nested. I do not know if I should add them dynamically. I know I have to do a For Each loop for sure (to loop over each 'id' in the Feedbacks array...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219650/discussion-between-hury-shen-and-lynnette).